# PostGIS - unique constraint for spatial equality

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon, sql

I have a polygon column for which I would like to add a unique constraint that tests for spatial equality akin to `ST_Equals` so that it ignores vertex order. For instance, I would like these polygons to count as duplicates:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1))')
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1, 1 0 1))')
```

Is there a standard way to implement this other than a GIST index, which the docs say only indexes the bounding box?

One solution I'm thinking of is to index on a function that returns a sorted array of polygon vertices, but it seems like a hack.

Comment: I just realized that you are using `POLYGONZ`; `ST_Equals` does not account for Z values. Might be why you suggests a vertice array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run a `CHECK` constraint against a custom function.

Create the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION equality_constraint_func(
  id INT,
  gm GEOMETRY
)
RETURNS boolean AS
  $$
    SELECT NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   <table> AS a
      WHERE  a.<id> <> id
        AND  a.<geom> && gm
        AND  ST_Equals(a.<geom>, gm)
    );
  $$
  LANGUAGE sql
;
```

and add the actual constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE <table>
  ADD CONSTRAINT equality_constraint
  CHECK (equality_constraint_func(<id>, <geom>))
;
```

---

Inspired by and adapted from [this excellent answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/270802/93656), to adress this rather common use case directly.

Read there why e.g. the `<id>` is passed.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's a good answer to the question I asked.  Unfortunately, I didn't realize ST_Equals doesn't work with 3D geometry as you pointed out. In light of that, I think the easiest and most performant solution may in fact be a vertex array.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and after quite some investigation I found a solution! You need to use `UNIQUE INDEX`, which encapsulates hashed normalized spatial feature.

```
CREATE TABLE GeomTable
(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Geom geometry
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UniqueGeometry ON GeomTable(SHA512(ST_Normalize(Geom)));
```

Let's discuss the functions that we are using:

1. We have used PostGIS function `ST_Normalize`. This will ensure, that geometry is normalized, no mater where is the start point of the polygon. For example:

   ```
   SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Normalize(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1))')))

   SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Normalize(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1, 1 0 1))')))
   ```

   Both select statements will return the same result:

   ```
   POLYGON Z ((0 0 1,0 1 1,1 1 1,1 0 1,0 0 1))
   ```

   Excellent! This function works for all geometry types + holes in polygon!
2. SHA512: This is a hash algorithm which takes "Something", in our example normalized polygon, and it creates a hash, which is always 512 bytes long. You can also use other hashing algorithms (SHA256, ...).

Let's do the test:

```
INSERT INTO GeomTable(Geom) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1))'));
Insert is OK


INSERT INTO GeomTable(Geom) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1, 1 0 1))'));
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uniquegeometry"
```

So we get expected result! If we insert the same geometry, we will get an error. I have tested this approach on Slovenian cadastre with 7M parcels (polygons) and it worked like a charm!

Because we are using `UNIQUE INDEX` we can also use "ON CONFLICT" action, which can be very useful:

```
INSERT INTO GeomTable(Geom) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1))')) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

or with specifying index constraint function:

```
INSERT INTO GeomTable(Geom) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGONZ((0 0 1, 1 0 1, 1 1 1, 0 1 1, 0 0 1))')) ON CONFLICT (SHA512(ST_Normalize(Geom))) DO NOTHING;
```

Because `UNIQUE INDEX` is an expression, you cannot use it as constraint.

Comment: @XOIOX  I'm trying to add an ON CONFLICT action, <INSERT INTO table ... ON CONFLICT WITH UNIQUE INDEX idx_uniquegeometry_geom DO NOTHING> but PostgreSQL/PostGIS complains about the WITH clause. It does not acknowledge the ON CONFLICT WITH/ON INDEX idx_uniquegeometry_geom DO NOTHING. Any comment on how to solve that?

Comment: @HelpOverFlow: Hey. sorry for the late response. I have extended the answer. Hopefully it helps.