# Getting "missing FROM-clause" error when adding ST_Intersects constraint to PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

I have two tables in PostGIS: afrivs, which is a polyline of various rivers, and weirs2 which is an empty polyline layer where potential dam sites will be added.

Obviously dams have to cross a river to work so I would like to add a constraint to enforce this.  Following the examples here https://spatialdbadvisor.com/postgis_tips_tricks/127/how-to-apply-spatial-constraints-to-postgis-tables I tried adding the following constraint to check that any new dam polyline crosses a river polyline:

```
ALTER TABLE weirs2 ADD CONSTRAINT river_intersect 
CHECK (ST_Intersects(afrivs.geom,weirs2.geom)=true);
```

However this gives me the following error message.

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "afrivs"
```

I also tried framing it as a SELECT query to include a FROM clause then get
 `syntax error at or near "SELECT".`

Based on this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149466/missing-from-clause-entry-with-constraint-on-value-from-type-in-postgresql, I tried putting the table names in () but then get:

`ERROR:  column "afrivs" does not exist`

What am I missing?

Using POSTGIS 2.4.4 r16526 on PostgreSQL 10.6.

Comment: Read the whole article. There is an example about making a constraint that is using two tables. Pay attention to `The only way we can check that these centroids fall inside the geometry polygons in the related, parcel, table is by constructing a function and using it instead of ST_Covers in our CHECK constraint`

Comment: see e.g. [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314701/93656) (my own answer, with reference to a more detailed one); change `SELECT NOT EXISTS ( ...` to `SELECT EXISTS ( ...` and `ST_Equals` to `ST_Intersects`, remove the `id` check (and parameter) and refer to your river table in `<table>`.

Answer (score 1):

It worked! Thanks ThingumaBob.

For reference the code I used:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_intersect(gm GEOMETRY)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
    SELECT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   afrivs AS tb
      WHERE  tb.geom && gm
        AND  ST_Intersects(tb.geom, gm));
  $$ LANGUAGE sql

ALTER TABLE weirs2 
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_intersection
  CHECK (check_intersect(geom))
```

For bonus points:

- It seems inelegant to have to create a new function just to
  get two tables into one ST function - is there no easier way of doing this?
- Do I need `SELECT EXISTS` or would `SELECT 1` also work?
- is there any way of having the `afrivs` table as an argument rather
  than hard-coding it into the function?
- what is the point of the `WHERE  tb.geom && gm` line - is this just
  to check that they are both non-null?

Cheers,

Comment: well, there is no 'simpler' way, and compared to triggers (that do offer plenty more options) often used, the elegancy of this did make me happy when I read about custom funcs in constraints. the `EXISTS` is special in that it stops execution as soon as it encounters the first `1/true`, `SELECT 1` scans the whole filtered range of rows. you can add a `REGCLASS` parameter to refer a relation (e.g. table) with inherent catalog/search path checks and thus security (although others types are possible). the `&&` is a bounding box comparator, used here to limit actual `ST_Intersection` operations.