# Unique constraint on Geometry to resolve INSERT conflicts

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I have a simple table with a geometry column like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE geomtable 
(
  gid serial, 
  geom geometry, 
  trip_count integer
);
```

I want a unique constraint on the geometry column, such that if the same geometry is being inserted again then, the `ON CONFLICT` clause should add the `trip_count` to the existing row.

So my insert query looks something like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO geomtable (geom, trip_count) values (<geom>, 123) 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT <equality_constraint>
DO UPDATE SET trip_count = geomtable.trip_count + EXCLUDED.trip_count;
```

I tried the approach to enforcing equality constraint as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/270802/18956) like so:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION equality_constraint_func(
  id INT,
  gm GEOMETRY
)
RETURNS boolean AS
  $$
    SELECT NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   geomtable AS a
      WHERE  a.gid <> id
        AND  a.geom && gm
        AND  ST_Equals(a.geom, gm)
    );
  $$
  LANGUAGE sql
;
```

And adding a `CHECK` constraint like so :

```
ALTER TABLE geomtable
  ADD CONSTRAINT equality_constraint
  CHECK (equality_constraint_func(gid, geom))
;
```

**However, this does not help me perform the `DO UPDATE` part of conflict resolution.** It just raises an error on duplicate geometry. I of course can't create a primary key out of my *geom* column as I get the `index row requires 42632 bytes, maximum size is 8191` error. I get a similar error on creating a unique index on the *geom* column. I tried creating a unique constraint using the above syntax by replacing CHECK with UNIQUE, but I get a syntax error. Is unique constraint using the function the way to go here, or do I need to consider some other approach like a trigger, or exclusion constraint?

My version information is as under:

```
PostgreSQL 12.4 (Ubuntu 12.4-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit POSTGIS="3.0.1 ec2a9aa" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="120" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.4.3 (Internal)"
```

Comment: Exclusion Constraints are index operator based, and `= (binary equal)` is all you can hope for. Triggers, Rules or text based geometry representation (`MD5(ST_AsBinary())`, `ST_GeoHash()`) are your options. I'd go with a Trigger.

Comment: @geozelot: can you give me an example of how this would look like or a some psuedo code? I am just wondering whether, I would be inserting the row, then check if any exists using ST_EQUALS, and then delete the row if duplicate, and perform addition.

Comment: Wouldn't && work for Exclusion Constraint? See [list of PostGIS operators](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/postgresql-best-practices-selection-and-optimization-of-postgis-spatial-indexes-gist-brin-and-r-tree_597034).

> && — Returns TRUE if A's 2D bounding box intersects B's 2D bounding box.

But it seems like it will not check for exact equality, [only intersection](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/spatial-constraints-with-postgis-in-postgresql-part-3).