# Polygons with same geometry and bbox but can't be aggregated with GROUP BY

Tags: postgis, aggregation, duplication

I'm trying to create a constraint unique on a geometry column to avoid duplicate ones, following https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299098/why-doesnt-my-unique-constraint-trigger/299107#299107

The function to populate the **new column** geom_text (since `constraint unique` on geometry column is impossible from what I understand)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function activite.conversion_geom(geom geometry)
returns varchar
Language SQL immutable as
'select Box2D(geom)';

Alter table activite.ouverture
add column geom_text varchar generated always as (activite.conversion_geom(geom)) stored,
add constraint geom_text unique (geom_text)
```

I can't create the unique constraint because it says duplicate **exists**.
But when I execute

```
select geom from activite.ouverture
group by geom
having count(geom) > 1
```

No rows is returned.
Fine.

Using the coords in the error message and QGIS

```
 La clé (geom_text)=(BOX(859646.1872923545 6933903.321689525,859651.5708820212 6933910.993510331)) est dupliquée.
```

I can see two polygons that seem *identical*.

So to confirm, using the gid of the polygons

```
select st_equals(o1.geom,o2.geom)
from activite.ouverture o1, activite.ouverture o2
where o1.gid = 230605 and o2.gid = 230606
```

returns true !
Why the query with the `GROUP BY geom` does not find these two polygons ?
And I am afraid that there are not alone...

Comment: Regarding the constraint on geometry, you can read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/380642/84870) or [that](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/372001/84870), including comments

Answer (score 3):

Two completely different geometries can have the same bounding box:

```sql
select box2d('polygon((0 0, 1 0, 10 10, 0 0))'::geometry), 
       box2d('polygon((0 10, 1 10, 10 0, 0 10))'::geometry);
     box2d      |     box2d
----------------+----------------
 BOX(0 0,10 10) | BOX(0 0,10 10)
(1 row)
```

[image]

Also, `st_equals` considers [spatial equality](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html) while `=` (used in `group by` considers plain equality, so if the vertices are not the same, such as changing the point order, `=` will be false while `st_equals` will be true

```sql
with src(geom1,geom2) as (values (
   'polygon((0 0, 1 0, 10 10, 0 0))'::geometry,
   'polygon((0 0, 10 10, 1 0, 0 0))'::geometry))
select st_equals(geom1,geom2), 
       geom1 = geom2
from src;

 st_equals | ?column?
-----------+----------
 t         | f
(1 row)
```

Comment: ok thanks. So what about `st_equals()` ? And I have indeed to modify the function.

Comment: st_equals looks at the geometry itself, not the bounding box, so in the example the two geometries won't be equal (despite having the same bbox). Doing `st_equals` on the two bbox will be true however

Comment: Sure but why `select st_equals(o1.geom,o2.geom) from activite.ouverture o1, activite.ouverture o2 where o1.gid = 230605 and o2.gid = 230606` _- without box2D - returns true, **but** the `GROUP BY geom` does not return these duplicates geometries ?

Comment: see edits showing how `st_equals` and `=` differ

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot ! So If I want to select all "spatial duplicates" regardless of the order of the vertices, `st_equals()` has to be chosen.