# Is this a safe way to enforce non overlapping polygons or can it cause data corruption?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, overlapping-features

In this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/270811/103732) and comments it is explained that it it possible to implement a non overlapping polygon constraint using exclude and a custom operator. This is using PostGIS and not the [built in geometric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/datatype-geometric.html#DATATYPE-POLYGON). I got the code below to run but am I making some horrible mistake that might lead to data corruption by doing this or is the code safe and correct?

```
CREATE OPERATOR &&&& (
    leftarg = postgis.geometry,
    rightarg = postgis.geometry,
    procedure = ST_Overlaps,
    commutator = &&&&
);

alter operator family gist_geometry_ops_2d using GIST add operator 100 &&&& (postgis.geometry,postgis.geometry);

create table Objects (
    id serial not null,
    geom postgis.geometry not null,
    an text not null,
    ac text not null,
    version integer not null,
    primary key (id,version),
    exclude using gist (ac with =,an with =,version with =,geom with &&&&)
);
```

Comment: looks good to me. Have you tried applying it to a large dataset to see if it corrupted anything?

Comment: I am trying that now but there are other bugs in that code base that I am trying to flush out at the same time so I want to rule out causes.

Comment: @GevaertJoep I am getting errors with some queries for this, see update, do you have any idea how these relates?

Comment: @GevaertJoep the error I edited in, and now out, turned out to be unrelated to this and have more to do with me not deploying the schema I thought I did.

Comment: sorry, this is not my exertise, so I thought I'd give you a hint on how to debug, but great you're making progress! I cannot help you from here sadly :s

Comment: @GevaertJoep no problems, I seems to be working as it scales up so I will have to wait and see if it keeps working I guess. Thanks