# PostGIS Topology with ArcGIS, is it possible?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-pro, topology

I have been tasked with developing a specialised asset management system, based on PostgreSQL/PostGIS given that it will be multi-user reading and editing, that will be consumed by and manipulated with ArcGIS Pro (a requirement), Geoserver and FME.

I'm currently in the data modelling phase, which is going well, though it is quickly revealing that I'll need to start using a topology to keep all of the data in check - and properly enforce spatial relationships without having to rely on editors to do remember to do so.

Some of the rules include (as an example):

- Gate (point) must be covered by PathSegment (line)
- PathSegment (line) must be inside PathEasement (polygon)
- PathEasement (polygon) must be covered by LandParcel (polygon)
- PathEasement (polygon) must not overlap ProtectedArea (polygon, separate feature class)

I'm pretty okay with PostGIS, as a straightforward geodatabase, though I am getting pretty lost with PostGIS Topology and how to implement it. The example rules above seem to be pretty straightforward with Esri's [Geodatabase Topology rules](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/pdf/topology_rules_poster.pdf), though that said I've read up on PostGIS topology tooling in [the PostGIS documentation](http://www.postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/topology.html), and in PostGIS in Action, I have to admit I'm quite lost.

Can I manipulate data against a PostGIS topology with ArcGIS Pro seemlessly, particularly for end users (in ArcGIS Pro)? Reading through Esri's [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-postgresql/data-types-postgresql.htm) I can't see anything obvious, and my Google-fu hasn't found anything fruitful, apart from [this](https://av.tib.eu/media/20343) which doesn't cover use in ArcGIS Pro, rather a custom web application. [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20121110152520/http://2010.foss4g.org/presentations/3555.pdf) was another presentation I'd found, but little to do with ArcGIS Pro.

There isn't anything really stopping me from using Esri's implementation of topology though I'd prefer to try PostGIS first as it's new to me, and I figured implementing it in a greenfield application would be a good way to learn it.

I find lots of diagrams and examples help, Esri's geodatabase topology rule poster makes sense to me though I am having difficulty understanding how to implement the example rules above in PostGIS topology, or how to 'glue' everything together?

Is it simply a case of defining rules once, attaching the topology to the relevant feature classes then simply add and edit data as if the topology was never there (the topology taking care of everything under the hood)?

(Edit: after a little more reading, [using constraints](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270769/enforce-postgis-constraint-that-geometries-do-not-overlap) might be a better way to check for some of these rules, such as 'must not overlap' using ST_Relate).

Comment: This is indeed a confusing topic.  Topology as defined by esri vs topology as defined by postgis.  They have some overlap, but are conceptually different.  You might be better off defining your topology rules as triggers (i.e. Gate - before update/insert check that `st_dwithin(gate.geom, pathsegment.geom, tolerance)` is true, and if false either snap the point to pathsegment or do not perform the update/insert).  Your rules are pretty straightforward so this seems like a better approach than postgis topology.